# Getting error while running my mload script

Tags: teradata, mload

I have been getting this error when i tried to run my mload script. "Mload: Command not found". I tried to run manually from command line. Command used : mload < filename.txt.

Comment: So either it's not installed or it's not in your path.

Comment: You'll need to install Teradata's TTU (Teradata Tools and Utilities) for whatever OS you are running. If you have already and it's still "Not found" then insure that the installation path is in your environment's PATH variable so that it can be found without referring to it's full path `/usr/bin/mload` or `C:\Program Files\Teradata\mload.exe` or whatever.